# What is the correct way to load a JavaScript library?

Tags: theming, javascript, charts

I am trying to display form data as a line chart.  I am running Drupal 9 in Lando.  I am using Charts 5.0.x w/ the Highcharts submodule. I installed the Highcharts JS library using composer. This is the relevant code.

#### .libraries.yml

```yaml
highcharts:
  js:
    /libraries/highcharts/highcharts.js: {  }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

#### .module

```php
function stats_degrees_theme() {
  return [
    'mychart_template' => [
      'variables' => ['chart_var' => NULL],
    ],
  ];
}
```

#### .routing.yml

```yaml
stats_degrees.render_form:
  path: '/statistics/stats-degrees'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Engineering and Physical Science Degrees Earned by Members of Underrepresented Groups'
    _form: '\Drupal\stats_degrees\Form\StatsDegreesForm'
  requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

#### .html.twig

```
{# stats_degrees/templates/mychart-template.html.twig #}
{{ attach_library('stats_degrees/highcharts') }}

<div id='container' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
  {{ chart_var | raw }}
</div>
```

#### Submission handler

```php
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { 
   $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
```

#### Form builder

```php
 if ($form_state->isRebuilding()) {
   // get the form data and build the chart
    // get twig template
      $form['#theme'] = 'mychart_template';
      $form['#attached'] = array(
        'library' => array('stats_degrees/highcharts')
      );
      $form['#chart_var'] = $rendered_chart;
  }
```

The template is rendered without chart. When I look at the HTML markup, I see the rendered chart code in chart_var and this is in the console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined at js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:4396
> js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:128 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function at HTMLDivElement.
> [anonymous] (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:4373
> at Function.each (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:2)
> at S.fn.init.each (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:2)
> at Object.attach (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:4370)
> at js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:139
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:136)
> at js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:365
> at HTMLDocument.listener (js_fLkad5FjTCYgrjWIVyhfUxVUTz4-TXopB2EJOzHz820.js:353)

When I drill down into the error I see it is failing here.

```js
(Highcharts)})(function(w){(function(b){function r(b,a){this.init(b,a)} var v=b.CenteredSeriesMixin,u=b.each,n=b.extend,q=b.merge,g=b.splat;n(r.prototype,{coll:"pane",init:function(b,a){this.chart=a;this.background=[];a.pane.push(this);this.setOptions(b)},setOptions:function(b){this.options=q(this.defaultOptions,this.chart.angular?{background:{}}:void 0,b)},render:function(){var b=this.options,a=this.options.background,c=this.chart.renderer;
```

Am I loading the Highcharts library correctly?

Comment: Have you cleared the registry? Does `highcharts.js` show up in the HTML source? Is the path to the `highcharts.js` correct in the HTML source?

Comment: Yes definitely check the path, the JS files are in a /code folder by default so the path might be wrong. You don't need to register the library yourself BTW, the submodule does that (see charts_highcharts.libraries.yml). Assuming the path to the JS is right and being loaded, I think the next question would be what does `$rendered_chart` contain?

Comment: I have cleared the registry.  
highcharts.js is under /libraries/highcharts/.  That's where composer installed it. 
When I view source the only reference to highcharts that I see it near the bottom under <script type="application/json" ...  charts_highcharts\/highcharts

Comment: $render_chart is too long for this comment but it starts with <div class="charts-highchart chart" data-chart="{&quot;title&quot;:{&quot;useHTML&quot;:true,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Number of Bachelor\u0027s

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what's happening is you need to add 'charts_highcharts/highcharts' as a dependency, like so:

```
highcharts:
  js:
    /libraries/highcharts/highcharts.js: {  }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - charts_highcharts/highcharts
```

(If this doesn't work, try 'charts_highcharts/charts_highcharts' instead of 'charts_highcharts/highcharts')

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting the same behavior with the same error message "Uncaught Reference Error: Highcharts is not defined".

Comment: Follow-up; the JS errors were only occurring when logged-in  i.e. the chart only displayed when logged out.  When I switched the theme from Bartik to Claro that issue was resolved as well.  The chart now displays when logged in or not.